# Mysql auto-increment + default value, non-primary field

Tags: mysql

I have a table CATEGORY_CD

I can't inline images yet, so the link is
https://s27.postimg.org/6z5gjxucj/Screenshot_from_2017_01_11_14_17_07.png

I would like to auto increment the bcode_prefix column, but it's not a primary key so is this possible? And if so, how can I set the initial value when a category gets added? I would like this field to be a static value for each category, so that all items added to say "Housewares" (category id 5) would get a barcode starting with 1000-

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post plain text, not an image. Use Control-k to mark it as code so formatting is kept.

Comment: Why don't you just use the `id` field, which does get auto incremented, instead of a separate field?

Comment: Hmm yeah that would work. Guess I'm over-thinking it. Thank you.

Comment: But the question still stands. If in case someone wants to auto increment a non primary field. This resource would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can auto-increment without it being a primary key. You just need to make that column be an index.